# force logout all locations

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, user-accounts, security

A nice feature would be to force logout from all other locations.

I login on my work machine (I have shortcuts in my startup) and also on my home machine.

If I were to leave that job unexpectedly I'd want to make sure that staying logged into the Trilogy could not be compromised by someone accessing my work account and accessing my account.

Another example would be, if I login on a library PC, or a friends PC I'd want to make sure I could force a logout from those if I forget to do it on the site by logging in at home.

Comment: This feature would be very useful, I always forget to logout.

Comment: Odd, I haven't wanted to logout since the day I first logged in.

Comment: I think it's your job to logout if you login from an untrustworthy location. Don't expect sites to patch up your mistakes. Would you logon to your bank account at a library and expect them to log you out? Its a *nice* feature, but first and foremost it's your responsibility.

Comment: This looks status-completed already - http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/logout

Comment: @S.Mark: Next time, you can just flag for mod attention (unless you've already flagged both posts in here). I went ahead and flagged.

Comment: Anyone any clue [about *when* this was implemented](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47433/monthly-summary-of-whats-new/47815#47815)?

Comment: @Arjan: [Found it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29040/remote-sign-out/29057#29057), and retagged so we can find it later.

Answer (score 3):

A number of recent browsers have temporary sessions that don't store cookies / history etc after you close the tab/browser - hence the infamous (and quickly ditched) [advert](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xB9fhjnJcB0) ("incognito" in Chrome, "InPrivate" in IE, etc).

Perhaps give that a go?

(I don't know what the bloke in the advert was looking at, but notice the similarity: "O.M.G.I.G.P." and "[OMG PONIES](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22164/thetxi)")

---

Having one button to log you out over multiple domains could be tricky... unless the site uses xss on itself ;-p And it would be used so rarely that I doubt you'd remember to use it in comparison to things like, say, collecting your belongings.

For your ex-company to abuse your account, they would presumably be committing identity fraud and possibly other similar things; if needs be, hit them with a lawyer...

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a global page (at least for [M]SOFU) that would provide the logged in / out status of all sites, with a logout link for them.

Comment: Showing a truly accurate logged-in status might be a bit hard to implement: how could the server ever know the cookies of the other SOFU sites are still alive? Showing a best guess might confuse users who just deleted all their cookies. (But indeed a global log out, invalidating the status known by the servers, regardless of any client cookies, might be doable of course.)

Comment: Perhaps just a global logout then. I think it would be useful, however you do have the cross domain login's to worry about.