# Remote Sign-Out

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, profile-page, tracking, logout

This feature is present in Gmail, but I think it might be useful in such an environment, also. What if we were to have a small box at the bottom of authenticated SO pages that show how many places an account is logged in from - in other words, **the number and location (by IP) of open sessions**.

This way, we could easily keep track of the security of our account, and if one were to leave their session open on a public computer, a **remote sign-off feature** would be very useful, too.

What does the community think?

Comment: +1. I think this functionality is brilliant, every website serious about security should do this...

Comment: One hour ago, Jeff marked this status-completed. Yay! @Jeff: how do we use this feature? Where is it? Thanks so much!

Comment: If you click on log out you get an option to either lock out everywhere or just log out the current session.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While [Jeff](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29040/remote-sign-out/29057#29057) does note you already have your last IP available, being able to time-out or remotely-kill another session would be nice.

The dopey way to do this would be to kill the other session as soon as you login from another machine, but for those of us who routinely login from our netbook, desktop, and work .. it'd not be so pleasant :)

Maybe implement an "authorized hardware" list like Apple does with iTunes purchases?

Comment: What if your imposter nuked your session?

Comment: @random well, we'd have a Nuke-Session War! Sort of like an edit war, but more... fatal!

Comment: @random, that was where my thought of auto-killing the previous session when you login again came from

Comment: @random: Killing other sessions isn't a problem. You just relogin and kill all other sessions. The attacker couldn't login after that because he doesn't know your password.

Comment: @gs oh ya, forgot that... and if needed, you could change your openid password too.

Answer (score 8):

You already have the last IP address present on your user account, below the "about me" box (visible only to you)

edit: I implemented a "Log Out Everywhere" button on the log out page. This clears *all* your sessions universally.

Comment: Yes, but what can you do with this IP address? What if, say, your laptop was stolen (though SO wouldn't be a top priority)?

Comment: This is different than what the OP asked for.

Comment: @kop ah, I see, you're right. Sorry.

Comment: thanks for implementing part of the feature, but could we also get a list of recent IP addresses, too (just like Gmail has)? This way, we can easily detect unexpected usage of our account.